# Improved delimiters for LibertinusMath

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, size, libertinus

I use for my documents the Libertine font for the text and Libertinus for the mathematics. I find these fonts generally very beautiful. However, I find that the delimiters are not very harmonious with each other.
Here is an exemple :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LibertinusMath-Regular.otf}
\delimiterfactor=1100

\begin{document}
\[
\left\Vert      \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right\Vert
\left|          \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right|
\left\lfloor    \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right\rfloor
\left[          \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right]
\left(          \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right)
\left\lbrace    \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right\rbrace
\left\langle    \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \right\rangle
\Bigg\langle    \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n      \Bigg\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

gives this :[image: Delimiters in Libertinus]

By way of comparison, here's what it would look like with the default Computern Modern font :
[image: Delimiters in CM]

The thickness and size of the delimiters is much more harmonious with the Computern Modern font. I think the Libertinus font have the following problems:

1. The thickness of the lines for the absolute value and for `\Vert` is too low
2. The space between the two vertical lines for `\Vert` is too low
3. `\floor` is slightly too big and thick compared to the brackets
4. `\langle` and `\rangle` are too small
5. (The fraction line is a little too thick)

Do you know how to deal with these different issues?

Maybe with a package?

Comment: They are all font specified features, so it's like asking to change the curve on a "c" with same solution you need to pick a different font, either for the whole expression or using the unicode-math `range` feature,  just for those characters,

Comment: What's the purpose of `\delimiterfactor=1100`?

Comment: @Mico It's for enlarging the delimiter. I think it's a bit more aesthetic.

Comment: 4. is clearly a bug and should be reported to https://github.com/alif-type/libertinus As for 1.-3., the line thickness of all these should be the same (in my opinion), but that is up to the designer.  Maybe raise a separate issue on the above website, asking for clarification.